# Unity 3D coding language, C# or JavaScript

Tags: script, javascript, c#, gaming, vbscript

Hello to the gaming community.
I am a budding game designer, learning to code for the first time in my life. I did learned c++ in school, 8 years back, so I sort of understand the logic when people are doing coding and I can suggest them the right route also, but to an extent I can't code. I am begining to learn coding for Unity 3D. Which one do you suggest is more versatile and easier to work on for future, because I am a game designer not a coder, I would do coding until I don't have anyone else to code for me. It should be easy and fast to learn, functional and universal to apply, and innovative at the same time.

C# or JavaScript ?

Thank you for your time
Ps- if you could suggest me steps to learn and tutorials to look for, that would be just awesome.

Comment: Sorry, this question is not suitable for Super User in particular, and  Stack Exchange sites as a whole, as it's up to personal preference and too subjective. See [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Unity 3D is a software ! is it so hard for you to google ? http://unity3d.com/

Comment: Yes, but programming and software development questions are explicitly off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a game developer, But I use Unity3D for applications in Architecture and Urban Planning (crowd simulations, Interactive 3d  Maps etc.). From this background, I would advise to go with JavaScript. The reasons are,

1. I find JavaScript (UnityScript to be accurate) simpler than C# in terms of learning coding.
2. You can apply any prior knowledge in web development directly in unity.
3. If you are dealing with external web APIs javascript can be right on target.
4. With the advent of node.js you can even think about developing real time web applications for your game using the same language (e.g. online multiplayer mode)
5. I find unity3d documentation for javascript better than C# with more and better examples.
6. I think generally there are lot more people working with javascript than C# and the    trend is positive for javascript, which makes it easier to get help.

The downsides I faced with working with JavaScript is that some specialised libraries/extensions (e.g. vuforia) are C# based and there are some features which are exclusive to C#. I don't think you'll run into either of these problems anytime soon if you are an absolute beginner to coding.

As a starting point, check this [link.](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/19302-Scripting-Section-FAQ)